# How can I make a string array display and make a new line for each string

Tags: arrays, string, newline

```
String [] arrData = new String []{"League Of Lengends#PC","Crisis 3#PC","GTA#Xbox","Dying light#PC",
    "Destiny#PS3","Skate#Xbox","Dying light#Xbox","Bloodborne#PS3","Crisis 3#Xbox",
    "GTA#PS3","Age of Empires#PC","Crisis 3#PS3","Dying light#PS3","Skate#PC",
    "Destiny#Xbox","Skate#PS3","GTA#PC","Counter Strike#PC","Counter Strike#Xbox"};
```

I can make the string display

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrData));
Output:
[League Of Lengends#PC, Crisis 3#PC, GTA#Xbox, Dying light#PC,..., Counter Strike#Xbox]
```

Now I am trying to put each game onto a new line

```
Output:
League Of Lengends#PC
Crisis 3#PC
GTA#Xbox
...
```

I have tried and haven't found a way could you please help me.

Comment: I updated my answer, I had left out the arrData.length.  That part will be vital for the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried looping through the array?

```
//loop through the array
for(int i = 0; i < arrData.length; i++){//begin for loop

//print each index on a new line
System.out.println(arrData[i]);

}//end for loop
```

Comment: Thanks, I just appended it to a textArea ,"GameList.append(arrData[i]+"\n");" and it displays

Comment: Your welcome, good luck with your project is it anything fun?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `foreach` loop :

```
for(String game : arrData ){
 System.out.println(game);
}
```